# Using babel & web pack with react without create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

My goal is to create a simple app and output one js standalone file and one css standalone file without using create-react-app.

I have two functional components like

```
const Card = () => {

  return(
    <div>test</div>
  )
}

export default Card;
```

My app.js file

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Card from './Card';

ReactDOM.render(<Card />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

It looks like I need web pack so this is my web pack config file

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry:  "./src/app.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "app.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" }
    ]
  }
};
```

I installed the following packages

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  }
```

Running nix babel src/app.js throws an error

```
Unexpected token 

   | 
> 7 |   ReactDOM.render(<Card />, document.getElementById('root'))
    |                   ^
  8 | }
```

The goal here to generate one JS file and one CSS file and that is why I didn't use the create-react-app.

Searching on the inter web shows a lot of results like using react and babel from a CDN which I do not want to do.

how do I compile JSK to pure JS into one JS minify file?

Edit

I did follow the other questions and this is the error I get

```
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.
```

.babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-1", "react"]
 }
```

web pack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry:  "./src/app.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "app.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query:
        {
            presets:['es2015', 'react']
        }
    }]
},
};
```

Comment: It doesn't know how to accept JSX. Check out the babel react preset: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react

Comment: Does this answer your question? [babel-loader jsx SyntaxError: Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460420/babel-loader-jsx-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075620/webpack-build-failed-throws-unexpected-token-error-jsx-syntax

Comment: there are MANY Stack Overflow questions regarding this exact error message in this exact scenario.  which of those questions did you research and why specifically did they not solve your issue?

Comment: I did and updated the question with new errors

Comment: Check this tutorial for React v17 setup without create-react-app: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-setup-a-react-js-project-from-scratch-without-create-react-app/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stripped-down working example that's not using CRA (but has CRA-like functionality) and outputs single file bundled assets: [Single Webpack Bundle Kit](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/single-webpack-bundle-kit)

---

## Includes:

- Bundles and minifies all `.js` into a single `static/js/bundle.min.js`
- Bundles and minifies all `.(s)css` into a single `static/css/bundle.min.css`
- Hot Module Replacement
- Lint (eslint) on save
- CSS and SCSS global or local stylesheets (similar to CRA, `.module.(s)css` is local otherwise without `.module` it's global)
- Image and font imports (`woff2|ttf|woff|eot|svg|png|jpg|jpeg`)
- Automatically aliased directories within `src` (using `~` will alias directories within `src`, such as `import Card from "~components/Card"`; this eliminates relative imports like: `import Card from "../../../components/Card"`)
- Includes notes as what each file in the `config` directory is and how it's supplementing the `webpack.config.js`

---

## Installation:

1 - Clone the boilerplate repository:

`git clone git@github.com:mattcarlotta/react-starter-kit.git`

2 - Run `yarn` or `npm install` to install dependencies.

3 - Run `yarn dev` or `npm run dev` to start a development server.

4 - Run `yarn build` or `npm run build` to create a compiled application to `dist`, then run `yarn start` or `npm start` to start a local production server.

---

Alternatively, if you're looking for the CRA that outputs single file assets, then take a look at this [answer (includes repo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59331493/combine-react-build-output-into-single-js-file/59332075#59332075).

Comment: Thank you so much Matt! JS tooling has become quite tricky. Any suggestions on how I can start learning from scratch?

Comment: When I first started building my own Webpack config several years ago, I reverse-engineered an ejected CRA (it also includes notes). Then, I branched out and started to refer to the [official Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) and, over time, added additional plugins (and wrote some helper libraries) to aid my work-flow.